# If array element is between 2 dates echo text PHP

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, array-filter

I have the following PHP code that I'm aiming to create an HTML email with that should output the details of all models with an expiry date landing between 2 set dates:

```
$sql = 'SELECT
GROUP_CONCAT(op.products_model),
GROUP_CONCAT(products.products_warranty_default),
GROUP_CONCAT(orders.date_purchased),
orders.customers_name
FROM orders_products op
INNER JOIN products
    ON op.products_id = products.products_id
INNER JOIN orders
    ON op.orders_id = orders.orders_id
INNER JOIN customers
    ON orders.customers_id = customers.customers_id
GROUP BY op.orders_id';

$result = mysql_query($sql, $connection);

while ($data = mysql_fetch_row($result)) {
    $models = explode(",",$data[0]); // create array from all models in the GROUP_CONCAT
    $years = explode(",",$data[1]); // create array from all years in the GROUP_CONCAT
    $dates = explode(",",$data[2]); // create array from all dates in the GROUP_CONCAT
    $name = $data[3];
    echo $header; // header of email (only the name changes on each loop)
    foreach ($models as $index => $model) {
    echo '
    <tr>
        <td width="149">
            <center>'.$model.'</center>
        </td>
        <td width="149">
            <center>'.date('d/m/Y', strtotime('+'.$years[$index].' years', strtotime($dates[$index]))).'</center>
        </td>
    </tr>'; // echos the model in first column and date+years in second column
    }
    echo $footer; // static HTML again like the header
}
```

What I'm stuck on is how to only output the combination of the header, table and footer if a model exists in the table where the date is between 2 dates i.e. 1st May 2014 and 31st May 2014. It's currently outputting all dates.

I've tried various ways to do this but after about 6 hours of failure I'm about ready to throw my computer out the window. I only have a few weeks experience with PHP (and programming altogether for that matter) so it may (hopefully) be a simple fix that I'm unaware of.

NOTE: I should note that with the current database I'm using to test this I could amend the select query to output the relevant dates but on the actual database I'm using (which I only have access to at work) there is no warranty field and I have to extract the information from the product's long description via php and feed this into a function.

**Final code:**

```
$sql = 'SELECT  op.products_model, 
        products.products_warranty_default,
        orders.date_purchased,
        orders.customers_name
   FROM orders_products op
  INNER JOIN products  ON op.products_id = products.products_id
  INNER JOIN orders    ON op.orders_id = orders.orders_id
  INNER JOIN customers ON orders.customers_id = customers.customers_id
  ORDER BY orders.customers_name, op.orders_id,
           op.products_model,
           products.products_warranty_default,
           orders.date_purchased';
$result = mysql_query($sql, $connection);
$previous_name = "";

while ($data = mysql_fetch_row($result)) {
    $model = $data[0];
    $year = $data[1];
    $date = $data[2];
    $name = $data[3];
    $expiry = strtotime('+'.$year.' years', strtotime($date));
    if ($previous_name != $name && $expiry >= strtotime('2014-05-01') && $expiry <= strtotime('2014-05-31')) {  // on a new customer name ...
        if ($previous_name != "") {
            // if there is a previous customer, write the footer
            echo $footer;
            $previous_name = $name; 
        }
    }
    if ($expiry >= strtotime('2014-05-01') && $expiry <= strtotime('2014-05-31')){
    echo '
    <tr>
        <td width="149">
                <center>'.$model.'</center>
        </td>
        <td width="149">
            <center>'.date('d/m/Y', $expiry).'</center>
        </td>
    </tr>'; // echos the model in first column and date+years in second column
    }
}
if ( $previous_name != "" && $expiry >= strtotime('2014-05-01') && $expiry <= strtotime('2014-05-31')) {
    echo $footer;
}
```

Comment: Show the schema of `orders_products`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems a bit strange that you're aggregating a lot of stuff in your SQL query and then disaggregating it in your PHP. This is making it hard for you to match dates, I believe.

You could try this non-aggregated query:

```
SELECT  op.products_model, 
        products.products_warranty_default,
        orders.date_purchased,
        orders.customers_name
   FROM orders_products op
  INNER JOIN products  ON op.products_id = products.products_id
  INNER JOIN orders    ON op.orders_id = orders.orders_id
  INNER JOIN customers ON orders.customers_id = customers.customers_id
  WHERE orders.date_purchased >= DATE('2014-05-01')
    AND orders.date_purchased <  DATE('2014-05-31') + INTERVAL 1 DAY
  ORDER BY orders.customer_name, op.orders_id,
           op.products_model,
           products.products_warranty_default,
           orders.date_purchased,
```

This will give you back the detail records, the ones that match the date range.

It's quite easy, I think, to then process that result set with php. You'll need to detect the change in customer name to output the headers and footers. That's what $previous_name is about.

```
$previous_name = "";

while ($data = mysql_fetch_row($result)) {
    $model = $data[0];
    $year = $data[1];
    $date = $data[2];
    $name = $data[3];

    if ($previous_name != $name) {  /* on a new customer name ... */
        if ($previous_name != "") {
            /* if there is a previous customer, write the footer  */
            echo $footer; /* static HTML again like the header */
        }
        /* write the header for the new customer */
        echo $header; 
        /* pick up the new customer name */
        $previous_name = $name; 
    }
    echo '
    <tr>
        <td width="149">
            <center>'.$model.'</center>
        </td>
        <td width="149">
            <center>'.date('d/m/Y', strtotime('+'.$year.' years', 
                      strtotime($date))).'</center>
        </td>
    </tr>'; /* echos the model in first column and date+years in second column */
    }
} /* end while ($data... */

/* wrap up the report by writing the final footer if need be */
if ( $previous_name != "" ) {
    echo $footer; /* static HTML again like the header */
}
```

See how this goes?  You request a detail resultset from SQL, and then use some programming techniques in PHP to divide that result set customer-by-customer.

That's easier and more reliable than getting a GROUPed result set and then trying to ungroup it.

Comment: Hi Ollie, this approach definitely looks promising, I'll give it a go.

Comment: yea I mean I need to rework it a bit anyway because I can't take the detailed dataset from the database that this will be applied to but the $previous_name principle is something I hadn't thought of before so will try again with this idea.

Comment: Works, huge thanks! I've edited the final code into the OP. I wasn't aware that variables defined at the end of a loop can be used at the beginning of the next loop... very useful

Answer (score 0):

Inside your foreach loop, just do an if statement to check if that $row  of data is within your date range, if it is then do your echoing, otherwise, do nothing.

EG:

```
foreach ($models as $index => $model) {

    if ($years[$index] >=  DATE('2014-05-01') && $years[$index] <=  DATE('2014-05-31')){

        echo '
        <tr>
            <td width="149">
               <center>'.$model.'</center>
           </td>
           <td width="149">
               <center>'.date('d/m/Y', strtotime('+'.$years[$index].' years', strtotime($dates[$index]))).'</center>
           </td>
           </tr>';
    }

}
```

Comment: Hi Andrew, I think this will echo a blank table for any rows without data within the date range as it's still within the while loop. It would still echo the header and footer for those rows.